# Unable to install cx_Oracle with pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, cx-oracle

I am currently using the latest version of Python and attempting to install **cx_Oracle** through the command `pip install cx_Oracle`.

On my first attempt, I encountered an error that stated:

```
Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools".
```

To address this, I installed both Microsoft C++ Build Tools from [this](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/) link and Visual C++ 17 from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170) link.

However, upon my second try, I encountered another error:

```
Temp\pip-install-ocqmu9mg\cx-oracle_a585471535c345cea9e48a083457ccd7\odpi\src\dpiImpl.h(34): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdlib.h': No such file or directory
```

I researched this issue by consulting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855090/pip-install-web3-issue-with-fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-include-file-io-h), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72301204/error-could-not-build-wheels-for-cx-oracle-which-is-required-to-install-pyproj) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49458638/can-not-install-cx-oracle-with-pip) post, but none of them provided a solution for my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice effort. Unfortunately, pre-compiled binaries for Python 3.11 are not currently available.

To utilize this version, you can either wait for their release or configure your system properly to build them from source.

Alternatively, you could consider downgrading to a previous version of Python, although this is not recommended.

Comment: Thanks a ton! Downgrade worked like a charm. I m not gonna use my app in production so using an older version of python isnt a problem. Thankss again!

Comment: The other option is to upgrade to python-oracledb, which *does* have Python 3.11 binaries.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have some very old dbs, thats why i asked specifically for cx_oracle module, unless of course if you know any trick to have backward compatibility with the new module. That would be even better!

Comment: python-oracledb thick mode is the same as cx_Oracle and can connect to the same databases.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. I m sure you know much better than me what is true (since you work for Oracle :D ) but in this link https://oracle.github.io/python-oracledb/ what does it mean when it says: "Thick mode: Connects to Oracle Database 11.2, 12c, 18c, and 21c"? This is what led me to believe that it doesn't support older versions like 9c for example.

Answer (score 0):

you can install `pip install oracledb`

Answer (score 0):

It was not made clear to me from these answers, but oracle has deprecated cx_Oracle in favor of python-oracledb. Python 3.11+ should install the new library.

> cx_Oracle has a major new release under a new name and homepage python-oracledb.

> The source code has moved to github.com/oracle/python-oracledb.

> New projects should install python-oracledb instead of cx_Oracle. Critical patches and binary packages for new Python releases may continue to be made in the cx_Oracle namespace for a limited time, subject to demand.

However python-oracledb does not support databases older than 11.2 - to connect you will need to use python3.10 and cx_Oracle

https://github.com/oracle/python-oracledb